# How to add SSL cipher suites to HttpWebRequest VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, ssl, https, tls1.2

I can't manage to securely SSL connect to a server through my VB.NET client. The server I am trying to connect is using TLS1.2 and accepts only the following cipher suites:

- TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0xc02f)
- TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0xc030)
- TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256 (0xcca8)

However my **HttpWebRequest** specified as

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
```

despite sending following 24 cipher suites none of which is compatible with any of the ones requested by the server.

- TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 (0xc028)
- TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0xc027)
- TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0xc014)
- TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0xc013)
- +20 different others...

**During the handshake, how I can add any of the server requested cipher suites within the "Hello" packet, so the server would not refuse the HTTPS connection?** Is this done by adding few lines of code (if so, please guide me), upgrading .NET, adding or modifying Registry, or something else?

Comment: Which dot.net version and which Windows version is used?

Comment: Windows 7 Home Edition, .NET Framework 4.8. Thank you.

Comment: AFAIK dot.net uses the schannel ssl library of Windows and Windows 7 does not support any of the ciphers you need. Upgrade to Windows 10 there the GCM ciphers are supported: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/tls-cipher-suites-in-windows-10-v1903

Comment: Thank you Robert for the reply. I contacted the server owners and asked them to add support of more TLS1.2 cipher suites, and fortunately they agreed.